# MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync() is not returning Media in Expo - React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, media-library

I am using Expo MediaLibrary to get videos from a specific folder and I am facing this problem.

**MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync()** shows there are no media inside an album. while there are media inside the folder.

> Code

```
  let album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync("GrabTube")
  console.log(album )
  let assets = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({album:album })
  console.log(assets)
```

First Console.log:

```
Object {
  "assetCount": 1,
  "id": "876214992",
  "title": "GrabTube",
}
```

Second Console.log:

```
Object {
  "assets": Array [],
  "endCursor": "0",
  "hasNextPage": false,
  "totalCount": 0,
}
```

In the first console.log, it shows there is one item/asset inside the folder. But as shown inside the second console.log it shows the folder is empty.

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I just saw your question. You need to specify mediaType along with the album.
Following is an example to fetch video files

`let assets = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({album:album, mediaType: "video" })`